# How to sign into Itunes connect

Tags: ios, itunes, apple-id

I want to distribute an IOS app using Test Flight. If I go to the Account page of the Apple Developer site, I can see my account details so I am definitely logged in.  On the left hand panel there is a Itunes Connect option. If I click on that it goes to the [enter link description here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/gettingstarted). If I click on App, then it has a link with the text 'Get Started'. If I click on this page, it goes to [a page](https://developer.apple.com/programs/), the top of which has an enroll option. But I  do not want to enroll, I want to sign in, but there is no sign in option, and in any case, I have already signed in.

On a separate page I have signed into Itunes Connect but that just takes me to the getting started page with the same result.

So how do I get to the Itunes connect page where I can add my app?

I am using the same apple ID to sign into my developer account and Itunes connect.

Comment: Your links are broken. please fix that so we can see your screenshots/links

Comment: I have corrected the links

Comment: Do you have multiple sub-accounts set up in iTunes connect?

Comment: I am almost certain I only have one Itunes connect account, and in any case I am signing in with the apple id for my developer account. I note that when I sign into Itunes Connect on the top right hand corner, it shows my user name, and correct email address, so I am definitely signed into it with the right apple id.  However, I do note that on the top right corner of  my developer account, it has the same name and email address as Itunes connect, but it does have the name of my company as well. Is it something to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called Apple support, and they almost immediately established there was an error in the setup of my accounts. They fixed this, and everything works well.